# Cлушать порт, не мешая работе программы которая висит на нем

Tags: порт, c++

Нужно слушать порт, не мешая работе программы которая висит на нем. То есть, допустим есть порт: 1234, на котором висит игровой сервер, мне нужно не вмешиваясь в его работу узнать какой ip адрес соединился с ним, может быть кто либо сталкивался и подкинет как примерно можно такое реализовать.

Comment: Посмотрите на `netstat -a` и программу `lsof`. Правда, это все в \*nix.

Comment: ну или библиотека pcap.

Comment: @KoVadim это не "слушать порт программы", но, вероятно, то что нужно ТС.

@avengerweb прежде чем что-либо писать, посмотрите, как это подслушивание выполняет какой-либо снифер, наприме WireShark.

Comment: Казалось бы, при чём тут с++

Comment: если не мешая даже не знаю...